# Hibernate query EASY answer

Tags: hibernate, entity, criteria

I'm working on hibernate. 
I have an @Entity like this:

Entity A:

```
int category; //1 2 or 3

List<B> B_list;
```

Entity B:

```
String word;
```

Now what i want to do is given a category of A and a word, i want to return all A's which match the category and in its B_list is has a B with the word equal to the parameter word.

This is what i have:

```
public List<A> getAs(int category,String word){
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(A.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("category",category));

        crit.add(Restrictions.//something to look for B);

        List<A> cats = crit.list();
        return cats;
 }
```

I have my session and all in order :) Thank you!

Comment: Can you make the title of question more descriptive? In your case, have something like Hibernate: Query by child list value using Criteria

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used criteria queries but if it was hql or jpql, I would just join to B and and the expression. ie

```
From A a join a.b_list b where a.category = : category and a.word = :word and b.<field name> = :word
```

In other words, you need to join with B on b_list and you can reference its fields.

Hope that points you in the right direction.

EDIT: You can do joins using criteria queries as well [using JPA 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjiuv) or [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-from-join)

Comment: Hi drone: Something like this might work, it has been a long time since i learned SQL and i don't feel that confident. I know this is not regular SQL but a.word does not exist so what would the a.word = :word statement be for? thank you

Comment: in the code I provided, a.word refers to the word field in the A class. The From A a makes a an Alias for A. You can also do this using Criteria Queries. I'll see if I can dig up an example...

Comment: Hi again. I'm so sorry i must be dumb but the Entity A has an int (category) and a List of B class objects. Now Entity B is the one that has a String (word). Is this the same thing you understood? Sorry :/ but I haven't been able to do this. Thank you again for your time

Comment: ah. then it should be `From A a join a.b_list b where a.category = :category and b.word = :word`. You will need to use [setParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setParameter) to set the category and word you are looking for